# Why is text not displayed on button click using Observable in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-routing

I have this code which is supposed to display the string representation of some data using an `Observable` when a button is clicked (Plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/wk3af4Va2hxT94VMeOk9?p=preview):

```
export class App {
    private data:Observable;
  private dataObserver:Observer;
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.data = new Observable(observer => this.dataObserver = observer);

  }
  hndle(){
    alert('---');
     this.dataObserver.next("navee");
  }
}
```

But for some reason the data just doesn't get displayed. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `data` is an observable you have to subscribe on it or use AsyncPipe like this:

```
{{data | async}}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ghEXiy5JpW6gquVnEMGM?p=preview)**

Comment: why it is not working if I take array  https://plnkr.co/edit/qvFcJ6kpQy70umqJKHBb?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a correct answer..!! could you please tell me why it is not showing list if I take array

Comment: Because you use global variable `name` and it's string. See this https://plnkr.co/edit/3Xjd1Q3SD9biP4hyvVSj?p=preview. You should use `this.name` instead of `name`